# Laravel 302 when i do a validation

Tags: php, laravel, backend

When I do post form in laravel and then validate it from the controller I get this response :
`302 found`

nothing useful, I`ve tried everything but nothing worked with me.

My Form blade :

```
                   <form action="{{route('newitem')}}" method="post">
                         @csrf
                         <div class="mb-3">
                              <label for="item name" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item name" name="item_name" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="price" class="form-label">Price</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" name="item_price">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
```

my controller :

```
public function new_item(Request $rq){
        
        $validated = $rq->validate(
            [
                'item_name'  => 'required|string|min:4|max:90',
                'item_desc'  => 'string|min:4|max:90',
                'item_price' => 'required|integer|min:4'
            ]
        );
        UsrsItem::create([
            'item_name' => $validated->item_title,
            'item_price' => $validated->item_price,

        ]);
    }
```

I hope someone can help me with that :<

Comment: so its redirecting because of validation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Contrroller Code

```
public function new_item(Request $rq){
    
    $validated = $rq->validate(
        [
            'item_name'  => 'required|string|min:4|max:90',
            'item_desc'  => 'string|min:4|max:90',
            'item_price' => 'required|integer|min:4'
        ]
    );
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
      return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
    UsrsItem::create([
        'item_name' => $validated->item_title,
        'item_price' => $validated->item_price,

    ]);
  return response()->json(['success'=>'Record is successfully added']);
}
```

> Put This In Blade File

```
    @if ($errors->has())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            {{ $error }}<br>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    @endif
```